# How can I import a CSV file for a large drop down list in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

How can I import a CSV file for a large drop down list in sugarcrm? Should I change the php file, if yes where is it located

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for that.

1. Create the list.
2. Look for the right language file in the right folder.

   - The folder, as said before, might be in different places. For me it was `<SugarCrmPath>/custom/include/language`
   - The file depend on the language (us_EN.lang.php if you are in english)
3. Look for the array you are interested in, it is the technical name of your list, you will find it written like this example : `$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['zone_geo_list']=array (`
4. Paste your list. It might be written like below :

   'key1' => 'value1',
   'key2' => 'value2'

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM dropdown lists are coded in PHP arrays in various directories in the file system. The lists themselves are not stored in the database. You will be able to find everything you need to know in the [SugarCRM Documentation: Language](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Language/).

I'm not going to downvote, but I suspect you were downvoted for not reading the manual before asking such a vague and unresearched question.

Comment: Why is it vague?!Sugarcrm allows you to put drop down fields. But in it you have to manually add the drop down fields one by one. If I want to add the whole languages in the world, doing this manually would take forever. I just want to import a csv file to be able to create a drop down for languages having the whole languages in the world. This can actually be done by modifying the files in the sugarcrm directory. I have already created custom fields with formulas using code and not front panel. I did my research.

Comment: It sounds like you figured it out: Sugar's dropdown lists are stored as PHP code (as arrays) in specific places in the system. Now that you've accomplished it, could you write up an answer to your own question? And maybe clarify the question to something more generic (original format e.g. CSV will not be relevant at that point).